# Reference JS using Custom Action Dependencies

Tags: custom-action

I have a site with jQuery referenced in the master page, I want to add new code to add functionality to the site and utilize jQuery. When I use custom action:

```
<CustomAction ScriptSrc="~SiteCollection/Style library/MyFolder/MyNewJS.js"
                Location="ScriptLink"
                Sequence="12"/>
```

to add my JS reference, it references my .js file before the jQuery file in the master page, so I keep having the `$ is undefined` when I use my .js file.

Any idea how to add the JS file after the jQuery file using custom action or to add it to the body of the page?

Comment: Any ideas??????

Answer (score 1):

You can try a workaround for this by referencing the JQuery from the custom script file instead of the master page. Here are the steps:

1. Remove the JQuery reference from the master page.
2. Add `document.writeln('<script src="PathToJQueryFile" type="text/javascript"></script>');` as the first line in `MyNewJS.js` file

Comment: Hi Nadeem, I don't have access to the master page, I need to make a solution and give it to some people so they can deploy it on their environment. So I need to have a way to reference my JS in custom action but at the end of the <body> tag, not in the head. Is there a way to do so?